# User has_one avatar, но book has_many covers, как сделать?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Я бы хотел иметь одну таблицу `images` (которая содержит поле `file:string`), и что-то типо такой структуры моделей

```
class BookCover
  mount_uploader :file, BookCoverUploader
end

class Book
  has_many :covers, class: 'BookCover'
end

class UserAvatar
  mount_uploader :file, UserAvatarUploader
end

class User
  has_one :avatar, class: 'UserAvatar'
end
```

Как добиться этого, что использовать? Single table inheritance или polimоrphic associations? Хотелось бы с легкостью отлавливать `images` c определенными `user` или `book` (к примеру удалять без `imageable_id`). Как бы вы организовали таблицы?

**Update**

По идее это должно работать, так?

```
# прием отсюда https://maulanaruby.wordpress.com/2007/02/17/sti-vs-polymorphic-association/

class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :file, null: false

      t.string :type, null: false
      t.integer :source_id, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Cover < Image
  mount_uploader :file, CoverUploader
  belongs_to :book, foreign_key: 'source_id'
end

class Avatar < Image
  mount_uploader :file, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'source_id'
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :covers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
end
```

Comment: Прочитайте мой ответ. И нет, в приведённом коде вы как минимум забыли о наследовании в паре мест.

Comment: Ой, ну да) ошибся чуть , а так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать (возможно, зря. но об этом потом), действительно делается **полиморфной ассоциацией**. Делается таблица, в которой "внешний ключ" (ненастоящий, но какой есть) представляется двумя полями: `штука_type` и `штука_id`, а Rails их использует при указании в модели:

```
belongs_to :штука, polymorphic: true
```

И задаётся, соответственно, противоположный `has_many` или `has_one`, с `as: :штука` (поскольку к полиморфу подходит всё, догадаться, по какому имени делать выборку, не по чему, нужно указать имя явно).

Но вообще полиморфы это приём довольно грязный. Контроль согласованности данных для них на уровне БД будет организовать очень сложно (если вообще возможно — я пока не видел РСУБД, позволяющих сделать внешний ключ не на всю таблицу, а лишь на небольшую подвыборку), а делать сложные запросы с участием этой ассоциации можно даже не пытаться.

---

#### Почему не STI?

Если вы для каждого значения `type` будете сопоставлять один и только один класс владельца, то вы получите костыль в форме полиморфа, где вместо `штука_type` будет просто `type`, и будет там не непосредственно тип владельца, а что-то, из чего можно его узнать.

Очень похоже по устройству на полиморф и все его недостатки тоже имеет.

---

#### Может, лучше выкинуть вообще `UserAvatar` как ненужную сущность?

Если в любой момент времени для каждой записи `User` вы ожидаете одну и только одну запись `UserAvatar`, то эти две сущности лучше сделать частями одной. Почему бы не сделать аватар пользователя полем прямо внутри модели?

И чуть более общее правило: если две сущности находятся в отношении 1-к-1, задумайтесь, не должны ли они на самом деле быть одной сущностью?

---

#### Поле для страшных экспериментов: [PostgreSQL и его наследование](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)

*Если у вас не PostgreSQL, дальше можете не читать :)*

Если вы ну очень-очень хотите иметь возможность лазить за картинками всех моделей сразу, можно сделать ход конём и воспользоваться наследованием не ActiveRecord, а прямо у БД. У PostgreSQL это есть, вот пример миграции и моделей:

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    # Базовая таблица с общими полями
    #                     vvvvvvvvv ВАЖНО
    create_table :images, id: false do |t|
      t.string :url
    end

    # Просто модели
    create_table :apples do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :oranges do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end

    # А вот тут самое интересное!
    create_table :apple_images, options: "INHERITS (images)" do |t|
      t.references :apple, foreign_key: true
    end

    create_table :orange_images, options: "INHERITS (images)" do |t|
      t.references :orange, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что:

- в `schema.rb` схема экспортируется с потерями, наследование успешно теряется, нужно добавить в `config/application.rb` экспорт прямо в SQL опцией

  ```
   config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`
  ```

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
end

class Apple < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apple_images
end

class AppleImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :apple
end

class Orange < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orange_images
end

class OrangeImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :orange
end
```

- У таблицы под `Image` нет первичного ключа. И, к сожалению, быть не может, поскольку PostgreSQL не поддерживает создания уникального ключа (а первичный ключ уникален, по определению) на базовой таблице. И как следствие, обновлять отдельные строчки таблицы обычным ActiveRecord'овским способом не получится, и поддержки коллбэков, в которых можно стирать файлы, тоже не будет.

Зато можно делать запросы вообще по всем картинкам, при желании. И добавление полей к `images` будет добавлять их и ко всем таблицам-наследникам.

Изучите, может ли это решение вам пригодиться. Оно как минимум сохраняет контроль согласованности внешними ключами. В качестве тренировки можете даже добавить **колонку** внешнего ключа в базовую таблицу, а сами внешние ключи создать в таблицах-наследниках.

Comment: Только `противоположный has_many или has_one` задаётся не с `polymorphic: true` а с `as: :штука`. (если я правильно понял, что обозначает термин `противоположный`)

Comment: @anoam да, забыл, верно, имя ж откуда-то он должен взять .-.

Comment: То есть has_one сам разрулит наличие только одного аватара в конкретный момент времени, даже если в другой таблице отношение has_many, и это без дополнительных манипуляций с базой данных? 
Почему не выкинуть UserAvatar: Конечно сделать в одной модели `mount_uploader :avatar` а в другой   `mount_uploaders :books` и `books` - это postgre array, но мне кажется, что если захочется удалить  картинки без родителя или по какойто другой выборке - то лучше, когда каждой картинке соответствует запись в базе

Comment: Я изменил вопрос и вставил  код, который как я думаю, будет работать (полагаясь на ваш ответ), так? и еще я понял, что мне нужно использовать sti так как cover и avatar должны иметь разные uploader`ы, но sti, который работает как pi

Comment: @BjornMelgaard вы ответ прочитали, но явно не поняли. Для чего вам вообще `UserAvatar`, если он состоит из одного поля и принадлежит всегда ровно одному юзеру? Что мешает поместить поле аватара прямо в пользователя, а таблицу обложек использовать только для обложек без полиморфа и STI вообще?

Comment: Я же написал почему: так легче проводить выборки, удалять картинки, которые никому не пренадлежат, так-же а вдруг я захочу добавить еще поле, которое будет касаться всех картинок?

Comment: @BjornMelgaard а почему бы сразу не стирать картинки, у которых пропадает владелец, и избежать не только решения проблемы, но и её возникновения? Если разместить поле аватара прямо в пользователе, загрузка нового файла поверх должна вызвать удаление старого. А если у вас есть поле, касающееся всех картинок и вас совершенно не интересует забота о согласованности данных на уровне БД, можете сделать и так. Стоит ли оно того, решать вам, но я б сказал, что в 90%+ случаев не стоит.

Comment: Хорошо, может вы и правы, дело вкуса, но код сверху должен работать, как вы думаете?

Comment: @BjornMelgaard работоспособность проверить вы можете и сами :) Ничего такого, что будет мешать работе, я не вижу. Но оно содержит все вышеописанные недостатки. Я сейчас смотрю, не получится ли ваш случай решить с помощью наследования в постгресе, больше из личного интереса, но это тоже будет страшноватым хаком, хотя и не таким страшным, как полиморф и STI :)

Comment: Ого, круто, спасибо, присылайте результат)

Comment: @BjornMelgaard во-о-от... смотрите. Если будет время, похимичу ещё, но пока результаты... не очень %)

Comment: Спасибо, @D-side =)